# How to round decimal places to 5, leaving the zero in fifth place

Tags: java

to display 0.45550 i am rounding it as

```
double dis=0.455504673; 
double roundoff=Math.round(dis*100000.0)/100000.0;
System.out.println(roundoff);
```

my output is as 0.4555
but i need it as 0.45550
plz help me to know how to add even zero to output

Answer (score 5):

Use DecimalFormat:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00000");
double dis=0.455504673;
System.out.print(df.format(dis));
```